# Difference between LIVE TABLE and STREAMING LIVE TABLE

Tags: databricks, delta-live-tables

When using DLT, we can create a live table with either STREAMING LIVE TABLE or LIVE TABLE, as written in the docs :

> CREATE OR REFRESH { STREAMING LIVE TABLE | LIVE TABLE } table_name

What is the difference between the two syntaxes ?

Answer (score 7):

It's described in the documentation, on the [Concepts' page](https://docs.databricks.com/data-engineering/delta-live-tables/delta-live-tables-concepts.html#datasets).

> A **live table or view always reflects the results of the query that defines it**, including when the query defining the table or view is updated, or an input data source is updated. Like a traditional materialized view, **a live table or view may be entirely computed** when possible to optimize computation resources and time.

> A **streaming live table or view processes data that has been added only since the last pipeline update**. Streaming tables and views are stateful; if the defining query changes, new data will be processed based on the new query and existing data is not recomputed.

Comment: It is not clear to me: `select * from stream(my_streaming_live_table)`: will that only return the latest data (that has not been read previously) - or will it return historical as well?  If the former then does that mean that one and only client can read from the table?  In `kafka` that is not the case: each `consumer` has an offset so an arbitrary number of consumers can be simultaneously supported with read-once guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

***when to use "streaming" keyword when creating DLT tables***

for ex.  *create or refresh streaming table table_name*

You can only declare streaming tables using queries that read against a streaming source (DLT)

***when to use "Live" key word when createing DLT table***

Live tables are equivalent conceptually to materialized views. To read from an internal dataset, prepend the LIVE keyword to the dataset name
Declaring new tables in this way creates a dependency that Delta Live Tables automatically resolves before executing updates. The *live* schema is a custom keyword implemented in Delta Live Tables that can be substituted for a target schema if you wish to publish your datasets.